# Is getBean() supposed to delay bean instantiation?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would expect getBean() to immediately call the configuration's @Bean method and create a new instance of the bean with SCOPE_PROTOTYPE. However, this doesn't seem to occur until a bean's method is invoked. Why is the loading delayed? What can be done to make the instance created immediately?

```
@Configuration
public class ViewModelConfig {
  @Autowired MyService service;

  @Bean
  @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public MyModel getModel() {
    return new MyModel(service);
  }
}

@Route
public class MyView extends FormLayout {
  @Autowired private ApplicationContext context;
  private MyModel model;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    model = context.getBean(IntegrationViewModel.class); // Bean is retrieved but ViewModelConfig.getModel() not called and new instance from MyModel(MyService) not created yet
    MyTreeGrid grid = new MyTreeGrid(model);
    this.add(grid);
  }
}

public class MyTreeGrid extends TreeGrid<MyTreeGridItem> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3198476593716788388L;
    private MyModel model;

    public MyTreeGrid(MyModel model){
        this.model = model;
        this.setItems(model.getItems()); // Before invoking model.getItems(), ViewModelConfig.getModel() is invoked, however the previous assignment of this.model is not updated with the new instance. Why is the loading delayed?

        this.addItemClickListener(
          new ComponentEventListener<ItemClickEvent<MyTreeGridItem>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8287268114264478411L;

            @Override
            public void onComponentEvent(ItemClickEvent<MyTreeGridItem> event) {
              // event.getItem() never returns null
             IntegrationTreeGrid.this.model.setSelectedItem(event.getItem()); // DOES NOT WORK!?! Appears to set the value when stepping through the function call, but after exiting the function call IntegrationTreeGrid.this.model.selectedItem remains null
            }
        });
  }
}

public class MyModel {

  private MyTreeGridItem selectedItem = null;

  public void setSelectedItem(MyTreeGridItem item) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The lazy init is because of `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`, which ends up with a proxy that holds a reference to the original bean *definition* and creates/reuses the actual target based on the context.

Since your bean has scope "prototype", this means you'll get a new instance every time you invoke a method on that proxy, which is most likely not what you want. Anything you do to that instance "gets lost", as a new one will be created on every method invocation (which explains what you saw). To test this, set a breakpoint in the `MyModel` constructor.

Scoped proxies make most sense in web contexts where you want to bind some component to the request or session but use/inject it as if it was a singleton.

Comment: I was under the impression that a new instance was made on each getBean(), thanks for the clarification! Is there a different annotation that I should use or should I avoid having this @Configuraiton class altogether and just create the Model normally?

Comment: You should just remove the `proxyMode` attribute from your annotation, as you don't need a proxy at all. Without that, it will behave exactly as you expect it.